What are statistics for the time between question and first answer, on average?
For general information and knowledge:
What is an average statistical value for the time delay between asking a question and a response being a first answer (that is not necessarily an accepted answer by the original poster) on Unix&Linux?
Thanks for that insight.
( general answer example for StackExchange )

The linked post has queries on Data SE, you could just run them for our site, e.g.: https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/9439

Statistically there is 1 question about every 33 minutes on Unix&Linux and 1 answer about every 25 minutes.
There are



Item
Number




total_users
564475


total_votes
2885784


total_comments
1225235


total_answers
353708


total_accepted
113990


total_unanswered
59845


total_questions
239999



which is about 180145 answered questions.
It's not exactly a measure for an answer to a question, but it provides a general estimation about average time between answers and a statistical average of about 2 accepted answers every 3 questions.
